# Do infinitely many prime numbers occur in $P(x) \in \mathbb{N}[x]$ when the coefficients are relative prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have read about Dirichlet's theorem recently,
that is, for relative prime positive integers $a,b$, there exists infinitely primes with the form $ax+b$.

What I want to ask is the situation when the $ax+b $ is changed as any irreducible polynomial with relative prime positive integer coefficients. Is there still infinitely many primes?

Comment: This is entirely unknown, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture).  We don't even know a single polynomial (of degree $>1$) that can be shown to take infinitely many prime values.

Comment: Note: it's clear that what you wrote is too broad.  The polynomial $x^2+2x+1$ passes your tests, but clearly can't take prime values.  Similarly, every value of $x^2+x$ is even.

Comment: Talking about polynomials in two variables, there is this : www.michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Friedlander-Iwaniec_theorem

Comment: I edited the problem to irreducible polynomials~ Thanks~

Comment: Note;  "irreducible" does not solve the problem.  $x^2+x+2$ is also always even.

Comment: I see~~ Thanks for informing and the Bunyakovsky conjecture really helps me to understand the issue.

Comment: So far the problem appears to be astonishingly intractable.  Even a concrete example, like $x^2+1$ seems to be beyond existing methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$ obviously is not prime for natural $x>0$.

**Edit:** for irreducible case you may want to read about [the (unsolved) Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture).

Comment: I have change the question into irreducible polynomials.

Comment: @SteveCheng鄭宗弘 updated the answer.

Comment: Irreducible is not sufficient: $x^2+x+2$ is always even, so almost never prime.

Comment: @xarles Yes, this is explained in the wiki article.